# android gson receive object as a list in string variable

Tags: android, json, gson

I am using **Gson** library to deserialize object that coming from **API** request  as **json string** and this is it's structure in API source code:

```
public List<typeBaseAirSegment> Airsegments { get; set; }
public List<AirPricingSolution> AirPriceSolutionlist { get; set; }
public List<SearchPassenger> SearchPassengerList { get; set; }
public List<AirlineData> Airlines { get; set; }
public List<FlightItem> AvailableFlights { get; set; }
public FlightSearchData FlightSearchData { get; set; }
public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

to this object class in my android project:

```
public boolean succeeded ;
public String errorMessage ;
public String airsegments;
public String airPriceSolutionlist;
public String searchPassengerList;
public List<AirlineData>airlines;
public List<FlightItem> availableFlights;
public FlightSearchData flightSearchData;
```

the difference between them is that objects `(airsegments,airPriceSolutionlist,searchPassengerList)` are string but in the base class was list of objects.

I want to receive these three values as string and don't try to deserialize them

I tried that code :

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
FlightSearchResultModel flightSearchResultModel = (FlightSearchResultModel) gson.fromJson(json, FlightSearchResultModel.class);
```

*but i have this exception :*

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 19 path $.airsegments
```

**How to do That ?**

***Thanks.***

Comment: If airSegments is an array of string from server, then use `List<String>` in your model class.

Comment: it's array of objects not string

Comment: then use list of those particular objects. Gson is used to deserialize the response string into your model class.

Comment: this object is used from built in reference library in the API i don't know what is it's structure i want it as a string and i will send it again as a string also

Comment: Then skip those field which you want as raw string, and use jsonParser to get those strings.

Comment: skip them mean remove them from java class ? if yes i want them there..if no so how to do that?

Comment: then dont deserialize those fields by naming them different names the use setter to set the data after parsing from jsonParser

Comment: tried your suggestion and it works now as i want .. thank you :)